# Naming conventions for a few operations (verbs) in REST

Tags: java, web-services, api, rest, naming-conventions

I'm trying to not use verbs when designing a REST api but struggling to re-imagine operations as resources (as in REST)

Here are a few

```
/guest/accountnumber/isValid/{username} (returns a Boolean by checking if account number is valid)
/user/associateAccount/{firstAcc}/{secondAcc} (returns a Boolean. Links up the two passed in accounts)
```

I really do not want to intentionally follow a bad practice and kill the spirit of REST but I'm struggling to re think this as resource state transfers instead of fowl XML RPC style operations or remote method invocations. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the boolean indicate the success of the operation? HTTP response codes can be used for that.

For the "associated accounts", imagine the *association* itself as an object. These objects can be imagined as being in a 'folder' under the account they refer to.

You could have `PUT /accounts/{firstAcc}/associations/{secondAcc}` return an HTTP code indicating whether the accounts were successfully associated (say `201 Created` or `409 Conflict`). `DELETE /accounts/{firstAcc}/associations/{secondAcc}` can be used to remove the link.

For your other example, I don't see exactly what you're trying to express. Is it just a check to see if an account exists? For that, I would use `HEAD /accounts/{number}`. It would return `200` if the account is valid and `404` if not.

Comment: Pretty good answer. However I would add that in general key to avoiding verbs is imagining actions and properties as objects. The best example of this I've seen: instead of POST(or PUT) to /rocket/launch use PUT(or POST) to /rocket/launches/ to "create new launch object property of the rocket". In more general case of isValid checks of exisiting objects you can try to get validity property (GET /accounts/{id}/validity ) or use it as property of returned object from GET /accounts/{id}